# Type 'User | undefined' is not assignable to type 'User'

Tags: typescript, koa

User controller:

```
import { User } from './user';

export class UserController {
public static async getuser(ctx: BaseContext) {
  const userRepository: Repository<User> = getManager().getRepository(User);
  const user: User = await userRepository.findOne(ctx.params.id); // error on this line

  if (user) {
    ctx.status = 200;
    ctx.body = user;
  }
}
```

I get the an error:

> error TS2322: Type 'User | undefined' is not assignable to type 'User'.
>     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'User'.

user.ts file (this one i import above):

```
@Entity('users')
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number | undefined;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true, unique: true })
  username: string | undefined;

  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  password: string | undefined;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date | undefined;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date | undefined;
}
```

Can't figure out, on how to fix this.

Comment: it seems `userRepository.findOne` is returning undefined, I would look at that method

Comment: const user: User | undefined ?

Comment: ^or that if undefined is expected as for 404

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error says, you're trying to assign a type 'User | undefined' (userRepository.findOne(), expected behavior when passing an id of a user that doesn't exist) to type 'User' (const user).

Since user can also be undefined, you have to change `const user: User` to `const user: User | undefined`.

Since there is

```
if (user) {
    ctx.status = 200;
    ctx.body = user;
  }
```

right after, I'm guessing user can be undefined.

Answer (score 3):

`userRepository.findOne(ctx.params.id);` may be `undefined` if no user is found. Two solutions:

Treat the search as faillible:

```js
const user: User | undefined = await userRepository.findOne(ctx.params.id);
```

Or consider that a User will be found:

```js
const user: User = await userRepository.findOne(ctx.params.id)!;
```

Note that this last solution is a cast, do it only if you are sure that a User will be found (in your case I don't think so).

Comment: Second solutions has no effect, it still complains, tough the first one as Jay Perl said worked.