# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I have created a map in typeScript i.e.

```
readonly stageTableMap: Map<string, SecureBucket>;
```

here , i'm putting string & SecureBucket variable in map in following manner .

```
stageTableMap.set(table, tableBucket);
```

when i'm retrieving value from this map in following manner : -

```
SecureBucket bucket = stageTableMap.get(table);
```

this is giving error as following : -

```
TS2322: Type 'SecureBucket' | undefined is not assignable to type 'SecureBucket'.
```

When i'm trying to change the dataType to `SecureBucket | undefined` , it's working , but i want to work it without any change in dataType .

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58149453/type-user-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-type-user) , but it's only referring to change the dataType to 'SecureBucket | undefined '.

Can someone please help .

Comment: What should happen if `table` is not found in the map?

Comment: You need to initialize it with `= new Map();`

Comment: Casting it to stageTableMap.get(table) as SecureBucket is working now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be SecureBucket || undefined because it doesn't have a warranty that the key you pass it's going to be in your map, if the key doesn't exist in the map it throws undefined as a default value.

using a casting `stageTableMap.get(table) as SecureBucket` may give you  a false assumption of safety when in reality if you pass a key that doesn't exist in your code on the run time it will return undefined, so `SecureBucket | undefined` is more true to your code

If you want to have a return type of SecureBucket in somewhere of your code you're expecting to work with the properties of SecureBucket so in that case maybe you should check if the key exists and if not re

Comment: what should we do , if the key doesn't exist . 
what should we return in that case .

Comment: It depends on your code, you can return undefined, an error or a default secure bucket